# Rails: How to setup routes that mimic Flickr's URL schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'd like for my URLs to look like this (similar to how Flickr has theirs set up).

```
/photos/username
/videos/username
/blogs/username
/photos/username/12345
/videos/username/12345
/blogs/username/12345
```

Is there a way to set those up as resources in my routes file instead of having to do a bunch of custom routes?

In the case of the `/photos/username/12345` URLs...the username isn't necessary but I think makes the URLs more readable.

NOTE: I'm using Rails 2.3.10

Comment: Is it necessary to work this way around? It would be way easier to have /username/photos.

Comment: you are pretty much going to have to set up a bunch of custom routes because what you are doing is not the "rails way".  The nice little shortcuts rails provides only happen when you follow the conventions :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Just make some regular non-RESTful routes

```
map.connect ":controller/:username", :action => :index
map.connect ":controller/:username/:id", :action => :show
```

This will route `/photos/shpigford` to the `index` action on `PhotosController` and put `:username => "shpigford"` in the `params` hash. The second line will route a URL with an `id`, like `/videos/edgerunner/35467` to the `show` action on `VideosController` and put `:username => "edgerunner", :id => "35467"` in the `params` hash.

You may want to constrain these routes a bit, so that they don't accidentally match other similar routes. You may also want to add named routes. A more elaborate setup would be:

```
map.with_options :controller => /photos|videos|blogs/, 
                 :username => /[-a-z0-9]+/,
                 :conditions => { :method => :get } do |route|
  route.user_assets ":controller/:username",     :action => :index
  route.user_asset  ":controller/:username/:id", :action => :show, :id => /\d+/
end
```

The `with_options` block applies its options to all the route definitions inside it, so that we don't have to repeat them every time. What this does, *in addition to the basic setup above*, is;

- Makes sure that the first segment is one of the three controllers we have (Otherwise it would happily accept `/zombies/fandango` and try to execute the index action of a nonexistent `ZombiesController` to fail miserably)
- Makes sure that the second segment(`username`) consists only of lowercase ASCII letters, numbers and dash.
- Accepts only HTTP GET requests. POST, PUT and DELETE aren't welcome.
- Defines these routes as **named routes** so that you can call `user_assets_path(:photos,'edgerunner')` in your views to render `/photos/edgerunner`
- Makes sure the third segment(`id`) digits only, so it does not match `/photos/clouds/nimbus`